# Program enum with Condtions with Java

Tags: java, types, enums

So I have this `enum` in java called `CargoStrength` and it stands for the strength of a container, my desire is to modify the `enum` so that enum type `fragile` only supports containers of type `fragile` and type `moderate`supports containers of type `fragile and moderate` and finally type `studrdy` which supports all three types. Is there any way in which i can achieve that with this...

```
enum CargoStrength{
    FRAGILE,MODERATE,STURDY
    
}
public class Cargo {
    private String name;
    private double weight;
    CargoStrength strength;
     
   
   public static void main(String[] args){
        CargoStrength strength=CargoStrength.STURDY;
       System.out.println(strength);
   }
    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "supports containers"?

Comment: Containers with that strength

Comment: I don't really get the question. I think you're code is missing where you make the actual check whether the container supports the strength or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to define a couple of fields in the enum, for example, `CargoStrength[] supported` to build lazily an array of supported weights on the basis of `int[] indexesSupported`:

```java
enum CargoStrength {
    FRAGILE(0),
    MODERATE(0, 1),
    STURDY(0, 1, 2);
    
    private final int[] indexesSupported;
    private CargoStrength[] supported;
    
    private CargoStrength(int ... supported) {
        this.indexesSupported = supported;
    }
    
    public CargoStrength[] getSupported() {
        if (null == supported) {
            supported = Arrays.stream(indexesSupported)
                .mapToObj(i -> CargoStrength.values()[i])
                .toArray(CargoStrength[]::new);
        }
        return supported;
    }
}
```

Test

```java
Arrays.stream(CargoStrength.values())
      .map(CargoStrength::getSupported)
      .map(Arrays::toString)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
[FRAGILE]
[FRAGILE, MODERATE]
[FRAGILE, MODERATE, STURDY]
```

---

A simpler version is possible without constructor, using enum's `ordinal()` method:

```java
enum CargoStrength {
    FRAGILE,
    MODERATE,
    STURDY;
    
    private CargoStrength[] supported;
    
    public CargoStrength[] getSupported() {
        if (null == supported) {
            supported = Arrays.stream(CargoStrength.values())
                .filter(cargo -> cargo.ordinal() <= this.ordinal())
                .toArray(CargoStrength[]::new);
        }
        return supported;
    }
}
```

Test and output are the same as above.